# Write a predicate which determines if a list is in ascending order

Tags: list, prolog, unification

I'm given the following predicates:

```
q8([]):-
q8([X]):-
q8([H|T]):-
```

which need to provide the following output

```
q8([2, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9]).
true.
q8([8, 5, 2, 8, 9]).
false.
```

My attempt was :

```
q8([]):-true.
q8([X]):-true.
q8([H|T]):- H<T, q8(T).
```

However this fails, because it attempts to unify the `tail` of my list to `q8([X])` which only allows for one element. I'm not quite sure how to get around this.

To make it more clear, if you run `q8([2,5,8,8,8,9])`. I get an error because `[5,8,8,8,9]` can't unify with `X`. It never gets to the third defined `q8 predicate`.

I'm doing practice problems for my final, so you guys aren't helping with homework! lol

Comment: No, the problem is `H < T`.

Comment: To clarify @TomasBy's comment, you're comparing the head of the list with the remainder of the list. You probably want to tear off two items at a time and compare them, then recur on the tail of the list.

Comment: Simply `ordered([_]):- !.` `ordered([A,B|T]):- A < B, ordered([B|T]).`

Comment: I agree, I'm doing it wrong, but you can't modify the left hand side. You can't change ordered ([A|T]) to ordered ([A,B|T]). Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
q8([]):-true.
q8([_X]):-true.
q8([H1,H2|T]):- H1=<H2, q8([H2|T]).
```

For the third clause you need to look at the first two elements in the list, you then need to use less than or equal, and finally you need to recurse keeping the second element you took off.

Comment: The question gives you the required q8 predicates, you can't redefine what's inside the parentheses, and have to work with the q8 as it is.

Comment: @cicero866: Rewrite the third rule above to `q8([H1|T]) :- T=[H2|_Ts], H1=<H2, q8(T).`. It expresses the same, it's just written differently.